# Endpoint authorization for service to service call

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a .net core API with multiple endpoint. I am using Identity Server 4 for authentication. Token will be generated based on correct user name and password.

In the Same API, I want to add another endpoint which should only be accessed by API call only and normal user should not be able to access the end point.

I am thinking of Policy based authorization for the endpoint.

Is it a correct approach?

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple things you could do.

1. As you mention you can use authorization policies. If you're using OAuth; your source API can use client credential grant type to obtain a M2M token (a.k.a. machine-to-machine token). In the target service can do a check the `gty` claim is equal to `client_credentials`, and if not; return HTTP 403 response.
2. Use the API gateway and only expose public APIs/operations on internal services - don't expose public routes for APIs/operations that should be restricted to service-to-service calls.
3. Do both #1 and #2.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to configure your policies. For that you need to understand the difference between authentication and authorization, and setup them both. For example in our project we use several different authentication sources, and then map them to authorization policies

```
services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddScheme<...>("scheme1", ...)
        .AddScheme<...>("scheme2", ...)
        ...;

services.AddAuthorization(opts =>
{
    opts.AddPolicy("policy1", policy => policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes("scheme1")
                                 .<some other requirements specific to this policy>
                                 .RequireAuthenticatedUser());
    opts.AddPolicy("policy2", policy => policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes("scheme2")
                                 .<some other requirements specific to this policy>
                                 .RequireAuthenticatedUser());
}
```

After which you could just use `[Authorize("policy1")]` and `[Authorize("policy2")]`. Or you could make one policy the default by adding

```
opts.DefaultPolicy = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
                             .AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                             .<requirements go here>
```

and then use `[Authorize]` to use the default policy, and `[Authorize("policy1")]` for special cases.